# CSS media query - bug or what?

Tags: css

if i write
@media(max-width:1024px) {...}
then these styles will be approved to screen width equal or less 1024px

BUT when i write @media(max-width:1023px) {...}
then these styles will be approved to screen width only less 1023px

i have some breakpoints that must have their own styles and this bug crushes everything
please help me solve this problem - i tried all that i can

Windows 10, Chrome
i tries FF - same

```
<div class="catalog">
    <div class="catalog-left">...</div>
    <div class="catalog-right">...</div>
</div>
```

for example such html code

i need to hide .catalog-left when screen width equal or less then 1023px

if i write

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px)
{
    .catalog-left {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

.catalog-left will be hidden already on 1024px width

but if i write

```
@media screen and (max-width:1023px)
{
    .catalog-left {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

.catalog-left will be hidden only on 1022px width

what do i do wrong ???

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a wrong question. Where is the code example? - [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] of what you are seeing. Please also include what browser and OS you see the issue with. See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: sorry
added example

Comment: @Kaner The CSS does `display: none` in both cases. You can remove the `1023px` part since the `max-width:1024` also applies to 1023.. Your error must be elsewhere (or this is not your real code?). At 1022 may be a rounding error and not a problem on your part.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I don't think he actually has both values in his code. He only wonders why, when using 1024 as a breakpoint its get included within the mediaquery, while 1023 isn't. As for this issue, it could indeed just be a rounding error and nothing else.

Comment: Okay that explains how the question is asked... a simple rounding error at 1023 pixels would be rarely overseen by everyone and immediately come up in Chromium and Webkit bugtrackers.. it is probably still another code which is affecting the element in question.

Comment: i think my monitor sets width a little bit more-
if use @media screen and (max-width:1023.9px) -
everything is ok

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out why.
Its because my monitor display settings was set to 125%.
If i changed it to 100%, then it worked fine.

[image]

So either, its a windows operating system bug or chrome bug.